# How can I check what is associated with a function name?

Tags: r, package

When I load `dplyr` and `Hmisc`, I get a conflict for the function `summarize`.

Is there a way that I can see all the functions associated with `summarize` and the priority. Right now, `summarize` defaults to `Hmisc` and I'd like it to default to `dplyr.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `conflict_scout` from the `conflicted` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(Hmisc)
library(conflicted)

conflict_scout()
# 11 conflicts:
# * `filter`     : dplyr, stats
# * `format.pval`: [Hmisc]
# * `intersect`  : [dplyr]
# * `lag`        : dplyr, stats
# * `Position`   : ggplot2, base
# * `setdiff`    : [dplyr]
# * `setequal`   : [dplyr]
# * `src`        : Hmisc, dplyr
# * `summarize`  : Hmisc, dplyr
# * `union`      : [dplyr]
# * `units`      : [Hmisc]
```

And if you want to set the `summarize` function from the `dplyr` to be in priority, you can use `conflict_prefer`.

```
conflict_prefer("summarize", "dplyr")
```

Comment: The OP only asks what are the conflicting function names, which is done by this function. If you want to set priority, use the `conflict_prefer` function from the same package.

Comment: Can I change my settings so that it always prefers `dplyr` in a conflict?

Comment: @Cauder Not sure. This link could be useful: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html